# How to properly deconstruct an array of arrays using hooks in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to turn a long list of objects (accounts) into smaller arrays of 6 or less. I'm doing this because I have a table in my react component that is listing all the accounts, however, it cannot hold any more than 6 accounts. I created the pagination and everything, and thought that it would work, but the current page doesn't ever seem to update.

```
const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(1);
const [numOfPages, setNumOfPages] = useState(Math.ceil(accounts.length / 6));
const [page, setPage] = useState([]);
const [pages, setPages] = useState([null]);

const onClick = (e) => {
    setPageNum(pageNum + 1);
    setPage(pages[pageNum]);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (numOfPages > 1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            setPages(pages.push(accounts.slice(i * 6, i * 6 + 6)));
        }
    }
    console.log(pages[1][1]);
    console.log(pages[2][2]);
    setPage([pages[1][1], pages[1][2]]);
    console.log(page);
}, []);
```

This isn't the final code, but rather part of my troubleshooting and I also think its where the issue is coming up. When I console log pages[1][1] and pages[1][2], I get two separate objects. So how come after using setPage and placing the two 'objects' inside of an array, does the console log of page come out as an empty array?? I've tried refactoring so many things. I've changed pages to an object instead of an array, i've tried doing it in another method instead of useEffect, all kinds of things. But the root of the issue seems to be that often my 'setPage' and my 'setPageNum' methods fail for seemingly no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare the pages array with `useMemo` (it will only change when `accounts` changes).

```js
const { useState, useMemo, useCallback } = React;

const Pager = ({ accounts }) => {
  const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);

  const pages = useMemo(() => {
    const pages = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < accounts.length; i += 6) {
      pages.push(accounts.slice(i, i + 6));
    }

    return pages;
  }, [accounts]);
  
  // console.log(pages);

  const numOfPages = pages.length;

  const page = pages[pageNum];

  const next = useCallback(() => {
    setPageNum(pageNum => pageNum + 1);
  }, []);
  
  const prev = useCallback(() => {
    setPageNum(pageNum => pageNum - 1);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={pageNum === 0} onClick={prev}>Prev</button>
      <button disabled={pageNum === numOfPages - 1} onClick={next}>Next</button>
      <ul>
        {pages[pageNum].map((s, i) => <li key={i}>{s}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const accounts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Pager accounts={accounts} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

The main problem in your code is the way you use `setPages`:

```
setPages(pages.push(accounts.slice(i * 6, i * 6 + 6)));
```

The `Array.push()` returns the new length of the array. So your `pages` state is actually the last number. It's the last number because `setState` replaces the state, and doesn't add it.

Comment: How am I able to set the page then? I tried using this variation, but it still won't let me set the page.

`const [page, setPage] = useState(pages[1]);
 console.log(page);
 console.log(pages);`

the console log of page in this case is still an empty array

Comment: You don't need to set the page. The page is derived from `pages` and `pageNum` `page = pages[pageNum];`.

Comment: You actually can do it. You are mapping an array because `pages[0]` is an array. Your problem is that your initial page is 1. Just change the initial state to `0`.

Comment: You'll also need to handle the case where the page doesn't exist (no items)

Comment: I've updated with a working example - the error was in this line `pages.push(accounts.slice(i, i + 6));`. I've incremented `i` by 6, but left your original slice `i * 6, i * 6 + 6`.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is `chunk`.
Since the data you are chunking comes from props, you don't need chunk inside the useEffect hook. It's not a side effect.

Here is a chunk function I found on the internet:

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var index = 0;
    var arrayLength = myArray.length;
    var tempArray = [];

    for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
        myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
        // Do something if you want with the group
        tempArray.push(myChunk);
    }

    return tempArray;
}
```